# RequireJS optimizer - Oracle MapViewer has more than one anonymous define

Tags: jquery, requirejs, oracle-map-viewer

I use RequireJS 2.2.0 for my project with the following configuration:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts/js/kendo",
    paths: {
        "kendo.datepicker.min": "kendo.datepicker.min",
        "jquery-ui": "../../lib/jquery-ui.min",
        "modules": "../../modules",
        "colorpicker": "../../lib/colorpicker",
        "eye": "../../lib/eye",
        "layout": "../../lib/layout",
        "utils": "../../lib/utils",
        "oraclemaps": "../../lib/oraclemapsv2"
    },
    shim: {
        "kendo.datepicker.min": ["oraclemaps"],
        "jquery-ui": ["oraclemaps"],
        "colorpicker": ["jquery-ui"],
        "eye": ["colorpicker"],
        "layout": ["eye"],
        "utils": ["layout"]
    }
});
```

`oraclemaps` is a third party library which includes jQuery. I use their version, so I defined Kendo and jQuery-UI dependencies in shim. oraclemaps has a component which requires `jquery-ui, colorpicker, eye, layout, and utils` in the mentioned order. This I have defined in shim as well. The application runs well.

The problem is now with the optimizer. Using the configuration, I got an error `oraclemapsv2.js has more than one anonymous define`. I googled it and I found that this is an [issue](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/issues/3) of jQuery Hammer (which is included in oraclemaps). Running the app leads to `mismatched anonymous define() module`.

I tried putting oraclemaps in `exclude/excludeShallow` and loading it in HTML, but I got `Script error for "jquery", needed by: jquery-ui, kendo.core.min`.

Here is my optimizer configuration:

```
({
    baseUrl: "../js/kendo",
    paths: {
        "kendo.datepicker.min": "kendo.datepicker.min",
        "jquery-ui": "../../lib/jquery-ui.min",
        "modules": "../../modules",
        "colorpicker": "../../lib/colorpicker",
        "eye": "../../lib/eye",
        "layout": "../../lib/layout",
        "utils": "../../lib/utils",
        "oraclemaps": "../../lib/oraclemapsv2"
    },
    shim: {
        "kendo.datepicker.min": ["oraclemaps"],
        "jquery-ui": ["oraclemaps"],
        "colorpicker": ["jquery-ui"],            
        "eye": ["colorpicker"],
        "layout": ["eye"],
        "utils": ["layout"]
    },
    include: ["../../lib/require.min"],
    exclude: ["oraclemaps"],
    name: "../../app",
    out: "../build/app-built.js"
})
```

What should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing the `r.js` optimizer can do to understand files that contain multiple anonymous `define` calls.

You have to find a build of `oraclemaps` that does not include multiple anonymous `define` calls. (Which means you have to get jQuery and of the Kendo datepicker else where than `oraclemaps`.) If such a build is not available, you could process `oraclemaps` to rip out the extra modules. Or you could process it so to add names to the `define` calls.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add names to the anonymous module? Here is for example, the part for Hammer. a.Hammer = e, "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = e), "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], function (b) { return d(a.Hammer, b) }) : d(a.Hammer, a.jQuery || a.Zepto)

Comment: You just need to add the name as the first parameter. Something like `define("Hammer", ["jquery"], ...`

Comment: I've tried loading my own jQuery and set noConflict to true, but it didn't work. I will take a look again though, haven't tried long enough.